# Image set of analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

As i konw image set of non constant entire function is dense subset of C.
Can we also say that image set of a non constant analytic function on every domain D(open and connected) is dense subset of D???
If yes, then how to prove it??

Comment: No: take $\frac z2$ on the unit disc

Comment: Or $z+2$ on the unit disk...